# Limit images sizes created by theme / plugins

Tags: wordpress, image, image-size

I am trying to limit the images sizes created by themes and plugins.
For instance, if you upload an image to a woocommerce product, I only want the sizes set by woocommerce to be created.

The same for my custom slider plugin; When I upload a slider, I only want the image sizes I set for the slider custom post type to be generated.

Then, to make it more complicated, I created a couple of plugins that don't use CPT, but instead an options page (like my testimonial plugin).

I thought this may work, but it doesn't.

```
if( get_post_type() == 'product' ) {
add_image_size( '1280-thumb', 1280 );//1280px wide, free high
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all, do regenerate thumbnails and set your image size with same add image size function then check if the image will be cropped or not as per your custom image size try with this one.

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180, true );
```

Using this plugin you can do regenerate your existing thumbnails https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/.